# How to generalize logic for two classes that do exactly the same but for different entity?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have two classes in my project: first do something with `comments`, second with `alerts`: `AlertFilterService` and `CommentFilterService`

They have almost identical constructors and exactly the same methods signature, like `do_somethig_for_alerts(self)` and `do_something_for_comments(self)`.

```
class AlertFilterService:
  do_somethig_for_alerts(self):
    some_code
    if
       code
    else:
       message['status'] = AlertStatus.NEW.value
       await self.db.store_alert(message)

class CommentFilterService
  do_somethig_for_comments(self):
    some_code
    if
       code
    else:
       message['status'] = CommentStatus.NEW.value
       await self.db.store_comment(message)
```

How to avoid code duplication? I wanna to have an abstract class like `FilterService`(that will have all common parts) and two concrete implementations. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have two almost identical classes with the other having a small difference, you can subclass the other by extending it.

If you want to have a single class, implement 2 different methods to handle the different cases or just make one method that accepts a parameter that will handle the case depending on the parameter passed

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
def select_val_type(tag)            
            if (tag== "comments"
                    val== Comments.NEW.value
            else:
                    val == AlertStatus.NEW.value
            message['status'] = val
            if(tag == "comments")
                    await self.db.store_comments(message)
            else:
                    await self.db.store_alert(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways you could go with this, so without much context, I'll stick to a very general answer.

This is a *very general / rough* implementation / use case of the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). See [this link](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/behavioral/state.py) for an implementation.

```
class MessageStatus(object):
    def __init__(self, status_instance):
        self._status_instance = status_instance # maintain a ptr to the class containing your attributes

    def __call__(self):
        # some code
        if some_condition:
           # more code
        else:
            message['status'] = self.cls.NEW.value
            await self.status_instance.db.store_comment(message)
```

> The state pattern is a behavioral software design pattern that implements a state machine in an object-oriented way. With the state pattern, a state machine is implemented by implementing each individual state as a derived class of the state pattern interface, and implementing state transitions by invoking methods defined by the pattern's superclass.

Note: Per the previous outline of the state pattern, if you wanted to make this conformant with the state pattern, I'd recommend refactoring your code such that the comment / alert status classes are subclasses of a generic state class, which would contain the logic above.